# How I can handle my dataset (insert a column that depend on value existant) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

My dataset is like this:

| ExecutionTime | Code | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09102021D081020 | HUUSNJUNJ | 500000 |
| 09102021D081020 | HUNSKMWKKS | 500000 |
| 09102021D093042 | NAUWJMKMS | 498333 |
| 09102021D093042 | SJIAJIJIJI | 498333 |
| 09102021D093042 | BHDYWHWHY | 498333 |
| 09102021D081020 | JHWJDNJWND | 454555 |

Then I expect to detect that when I have 2 lines ExecutionTime is the same, it is Type 1, 3 lines ExecutionTime same, it is Type 2 and I get that line to new dataframe like this:

| ExecutionTime | Code | Type of Operation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09102021D081020 | HUUSNJUNJ | Type 1 |
| 09102021D093042 | NAUWJMKMS | Type 2 |

Welcome to any idea and suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about consecutive rows? There are 3 ExecutionTime with `09102021D081020` as well. Or should the amount be used for grouping? What about counts other than 2 and 3?

Comment: I want to define them when ExecutionTime repeatedly, like identification that it's a kind of type of operation.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, You can use groupby on `"ExecutionTime","Amount"` and transform the count, then with a helper dictionary, map the values and then aggregate first with groupby on ExecutionTime:

```
s = df.groupby(["ExecutionTime","Amount"])['ExecutionTime'].transform('count')
d = {2:'Type 1',3:'Type 2'} #expand your dict as necessary
out = (df.assign(Type=s.map(d)).groupby('ExecutionTime',as_index=False)
       [['Code','Type']].first())
```

---

```
print(out)

     ExecutionTime       Code    Type
0  09102021D081020  HUUSNJUNJ  Type 1
1  09102021D093042  NAUWJMKMS  Type 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_df = (
    df.assign(
        **{'Type of Operation': (
            df.groupby(
                df.ExecutionTime.ne(
                    df.ExecutionTime.shift(1)
                ).cumsum()
            )['Code']
            .transform(lambda x: f'Type {x.shape[0] - 1}')
        )}
    )
    .drop_duplicates(['Type of Operation'])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
     ExecutionTime        Code  Amount Type of Operation
0  09102021D081020   HUUSNJUNJ  500000            Type 1
1  09102021D093042   NAUWJMKMS  498333            Type 2
2  09102021D081020  JHWJDNJWND  454555            Type 0
```

Compact version:

```
df.assign(**{'Type of Operation':df.groupby(df.ExecutionTime.ne(df.ExecutionTime.shift(1)).cumsum())['Code'].transform(lambda x: f'Type {x.shape[0] - 1}')}).drop_duplicates(['Type of Operation']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to group by ExecutionTime and Amount and only keep the groups with 2 or 3 rows. Use `groupby` with a custom function and a `defaultdict`, then `dropna`

```
from collections import defaultdict
maps = defaultdict(lambda:None, {2: 'Type 1', 3: 'Type 2'})

(df.groupby(['ExecutionTime', 'Amount'])['Code']
   .agg([('Code', 'first'), ('Type of operation', lambda s: maps[s.count()])])
   .dropna(subset=['Type of operation'])
   .droplevel(1)
)
```

output:

```
                      Code Type of operation
ExecutionTime                               
09102021D081020  HUUSNJUNJ            Type 1
09102021D093042  NAUWJMKMS            Type 2
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you! It is working, but you can suggest me how I can add more conditions to groupby, like, if I have 2 ExecutionTime repeatedly and same Amount, it's gonna be Type 1, and 2 ExecutionTime repeatedly and same Code, it's gonna be Type 4?
I try but it's not logical